# How would a native speaker interpret (or understand) the word "weal"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, synonyms

It seems there are several possible translations for the word "**Weal**".

Does the notion of "well-being" come to your mind when you read or hear that word?

What comes to a native English speaker's mind? (I'm French)

Comment: A painful blister comes to my mind. Have you checked a dictionary? Google images : [**weals**](https://www.google.com/search?q=weals&num=20&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI_YXcxa3cAhWDIpoKHTwGDmIQ_AUICigB&biw=1305&bih=619)

Comment: Yes, but using WordReference application, or even Google Translate, it relates also the notion of "Well-being". 
Type "Weal" on Google Translate and you will notice.

Comment: you asked, I replied. That was my very first thought.

Comment: "Weal" in the sense of well-being comes from Old English and is pretty archaic these days. Hopefully, anyone writing the word today would provide sufficient context to make that clear.

Comment: Aside from the use to mean a "raised area on the skin", it's an archaic term and most (US) English speakers would not know how to precisely interpret it.  In the US you probably most often see it used (in the well-being sense) as a part of the (also archaic) term "commonweal".

Comment: Collins marks the sense related to well-being as "archaic" and in (Banking & Finance) as "obsolete". https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/weal

Comment: For Google, Jordan comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**weal**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/weal)

> 1. Prosperity; happiness: in weal and woe.
> 2. The welfare of the community; the general good: the public weal.

Seen occasionally written, heard spoken much less so.

What comes to this AmE speaker's mind:

> A ridge on the flesh raised by a blow; a welt.

Comment: See my comment at OP.